# How to get list of settings in android

Tags: java, android, settings

Does anyone know where can I find a full list of settings?

This is my code it works, the only problem I have I cannot find the line to bring up the google voice settings I'm looking for:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}else {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Google is your friend. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Comment: Thanks, i actually figured it out Google voice settings are actually not a part of the system settings it uses a google package and i have to access it a different way- think i ll figure it out eventually : )

Comment: Under Android Studio (2021.3.1.17) & SDK 33, I am getting "Class referenced in the manifest, com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS , was not found in the project or the libraries". Any idea how to solve this?